# Still cannot override bootstrap variables in twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I apologize in advance if I seem to be 'flogging a dead problem'.  It seems like this problem has been answered a million and one times but for some reason I still cannot seem to `change the color of the bootstrap navbar`.  Please help!!

My `application.css.scss` looks like this

```
*/
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

My `framework_and_overrides.css.scss` looks like this (the first 10 lines that is)

```
// Changes I want to make to the navbar color

$navbar-default-bg: #312312;
$light-orange: #ff8c00;
$navbar-default-color: $light-orange;

@import "bootstrap";
```

I have also tried the following in my terminal

```
$ rake assets:clean
$ rake assets:precompile
```

Is there something else I need to be doing? :-<

Comment: I figured out a way of overriding it by doing the following (in framework_and_overrides.css.scss)    ' .navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #242045 !important;
  border-color: #242045 !important;
} '

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something here, isn't setting $light-orange redundant? This should fix your problem.

```
$navbar-default-bg: #312312;
$navbar-default-color: #ff8c00;

@import "bootstrap";
```